# Making div tag invisible on page load and display several div tags on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a div tag invisible when the page loads and make it visible everytime a button is clicked. This is what I have on my page:

```
 <div id="realProp1">
    <input name="FirstName[0]" class="form-control" />
</div>

 <div id="realProp2">
    <input name="FirstName[1]" class="form-control" />
</div>

 <div id="realProp3">
    <input name="FirstName[2]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="AddItem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
```

Whenever AddItem button is clicked, I want to display one Div tag/item so if I click "Add Item" button, I want to make visible only div tag "realProp1", now if I click "AddItem" button again, I want to make visible "realProp2" div tag. Below is what I have, the code is working for one div tag, but not for several div tags:

```
 <script>
         window.onload = function () {
              
                document.getElementById("realProp1").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("realProp2").style.display = 'none';


document.getElementById("realProp3").style.display = 'none';
                
            };

 function Additem() {
                document.getElementById("realProp1").style.display = "";
            };

 </script>
```

How can I make one div tag visible at each button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:eq()` to compare which div to show and save some variable for holding the last count value or you can just use `$("div[id^=realProp]").filter(":hidden").first().show()` for filtering the `hidden` divs and showing first div always.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('div[id^=realProp]').hide();

var count = 0;
$('.show_div').on('click', function() {
  $('div[id^=realProp]:eq(' + count + ')').show(); //show div
  count++; //for next div to show

  //or without count ..use below 
  //show first div..by filtering hidden divs
  //$("div[id^=realProp]").filter(":hidden").first().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="realProp1">
  <input name="FirstName[0]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="realProp2">
  <input name="FirstName[1]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="realProp3">
  <input name="FirstName[2]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary show_div">Add Item</button>
```

***Without jquery*** :

```js
var length = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='realProp']").length;
var count = 1; //for holding last visible div count

function AddItem() {
  if (count <= length) {
    document.getElementById("realProp" + count).style.display = "block"; //show..
    count++;
  } else {
    console.log("No more divs")
  }

};
```

```css
div[id^='realProp'] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="realProp1">
  <input name="FirstName[0]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="realProp2">
  <input name="FirstName[1]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="realProp3">
  <input name="FirstName[2]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="AddItem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let count = 1;

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("realProp1").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("realProp2").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("realProp3").style.display = 'none';

};


function AddItem() {
  for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById("realProp" + i).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById("realProp" + count).style.display = "";
  if (count <3 ){
    count++;
  } else {
   count = 1;
   } 
};
```

```html
<div id="realProp1">
  <input name="FirstName[0]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="realProp2">
  <input name="FirstName[1]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div id="realProp3">
  <input name="FirstName[2]" class="form-control" />
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="AddItem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
```